# spark-highcharts export to file (png or pdf)

Tags: apache-spark, highcharts

I have been using [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) with zeppelin. Through simple examples like:

```
val chart = highcharts(dataFrame
  .seriesCol("city")
  .series("y" -> col("temperature")))

chart.plot()
```

But I do not know how to export the SVG or PDF of the same plot directly through my code to a file. I remember there was an example of it but sadly I cannot find it anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `html` is designed for this case. It will generate a html page which include interaction function. It can be send and share with other users.

```
chart.html(path, filename, open)
```

after get the html file, you can save or print as PDF file.

Comment: Great I miss that but is there a way to just output the pdf itself?

Comment: In html page, there is an export button which can be export to PDF. So it shall be theoratically possible directly through spark-highcharts. But it has not done yet. You are welcome to have a pull request.